# Is there any Bigdata tool to process pdf document

Tags: java, pdf, hadoop, bigdata

I have to process PDF document.
Is there any tool in Bigdata to process my pdf documents(semi structured data)??
for example..
if my PDF document contains any topics like summary or action any thing i have to retrieve those paragraph with out any footer.
Now I am using pdfBox & java API to extract my pdf document but is there any bigdata tool available to do the same extraction??

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a tool to do what you want to do, but if you are OK with setting up a Hadoop cluster (or using Amazon AWS services), then you can easily use Hadoop streaming to pass PDF documents through a user-defined program (what you have in java should work fine).

There is a good example of how to use Hadoop streaming with a custom Java program in [this earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235178/running-a-java-application-via-a-script-when-using-hadoop-streaming-java-lang-n).